# How to implement Always Encrypted into a Spring Boot Application using Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, azure-cosmosdb, always-encrypted

I wanted to implement an Always Encrypted feature in my SpringBoot application using CosmosDB. I know microsoft dicates to use a Windows Environment or Docker to run MSSQL but I believe there must be a way to implemented inside the application using JDBC.

I have tried this solution but I could not make it work, even after seing his example he uses gradle and uses Java Keystore instead of Azure Keyvault and with Cosmos DB. I tried replacing and following Microsoft guides but I am confused on the correct implementation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently supported by the Cosmos DB Spring Data SDK. Only the core .NET and Java SDK's support the always encrypted feature in Azure.